# Align text columns in javascript alert

Tags: javascript, alert, text-alignment

I have a javascript alert where I'm showing pairs of values one per line in a box that asks the user to confirm that they want to delete a record.

Something like this:

```
header1: value1   
header2: value2   
header3: value3
```

The problem is when the header's can greatly vary in length. Something like:

```
h1: value1
longlongheader2: value2
```

I can't make any useful assumptions about the length of the headers. But I need "value2" to be directly below "value1".

I can't use the length of the string, since visually `O` is **much** bigger than `i`. Does javascript have a way to measure font metrics?

I was surprised that I couldn't find an answer to this. Everything I'd seen was specific for other languages, or everyone had recommended libraries.

I should also point out, that I'd prefer not to include any libraries for this. Currently running standard JQuery, but not JQueryUI.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? In JSON for example.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet The headers come from table headers, and the values are corresponding to the values in the table for a particular row. I can't really make any assumptions on the kind of data that will be there. Any sample data would be circumstantial

Comment: We can assume it is as simple object as keys/values then.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet more specifically text to text keys/values yes. But I mean, no assumptions about what kind of text is there.

Comment: `since visually O is much bigger than i` This is the biggest issue IMO as you do not have any control on how the alert will be shown. A solution could be to use a custom alert.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet Holy crap. It's worse than I thought. I even found cases where it would be lined up in a span, but in an alert they're not. Do you by any chance know what font IE 8 uses for their alert boxes? How can I find out

Comment: I think you are going into a lot of pain by using browser's native alert. Why don't you use a custom alert and wrap everything into a table?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tab space escape sequence `\t` to provide exact spaces between header and values like below:

```
var message = "header:\t\tvalue1"
message += "\n"
message += "longheader:\tvalue2"
alert(message);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tvxs665m/)**

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I need this to work for arbitrary length headers. This only works if I know the header values ahead of time. From the question: "I can't make any useful assumptions about the length of the headers"

Comment: So you question should like how to know the length of headers, Provide some code of JS so that we get an idea about it.